# Why do I receive no column error in python sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def insert_sub(self, uname, number):
    insert = 'UPDATE accDATA SET subscribers = {} WHERE username = {}'.format(number, uname)
    self.c.execute(insert)
    self.conn.commit()
```

I changed out the uname in the format with number and it worked without a problem.  For some reason when I use uname it tells me there is no such column. Also when i just take out the second format and just hard code in the name it also works fine.

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Bradley

Comment: please send details of your `accDATA` table

Comment: It has three columns: username TEXT, password TEXT, subscribers INTEGER

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659616/no-such-column-error-in-python

Comment: so there is not column name `Bradley` !

Comment: That worked, so thank you, but why is it that .format works for number but not uname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be missing quotes around your formatted username. It's not recommended to build a query like this with the .format() method as this could lead to sql injection.  However, in terms of the immediate issue that you are seeing it's most likely the quotations.

```
def insert_sub(self, uname, number):
   insert = 'UPDATE accDATA SET subscribers = {} WHERE username = \'{}\''.format(number, uname)
   self.c.execute(insert)
   self.conn.commit()
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) is the documentation on passing parameters into the cursor.execute method.

Below is an example with using parameterized statements.

```
def insert_sub(self, uname, number):
    self.c.execute(
        "UPDATE accDATA SET subscribers=? WHERE username=?",
        (uname, number,)
    )
```

Comment: appreciate the documentation

Comment: No problem @BradleyRay.  Glad to help out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `"` around `{}` when assigning to insert

But try using this type of inserting to prevent it against SQL injection

```py
self.c.execute('UPDATE accDATA SET subscribers = ? WHERE username = ?', (number, uname))
```